# Sci-fi movie or anthology series episode where son discovers dad may be an alien imposter

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

• The movie/episode was about the son in a family who grew suspicious of his dad.

• There was a bright light in the garage and the dad was somehow involved. Dad maybe turned into an alien clone of himself.

• I saw it about 1 year ago on either Prime Video, HBO Nordic (now HBO Max) or Apple TV. But regional differences might make this irrelevant.

• the son was tech-y and had pretty new technology. So I assume it was a pretty new movie/series. Definitely not older than 2013 or something.

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like [The Father Thing](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt6701648/?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep7) from the [Electric Dreams](https://imdb.com/title/tt5711280/) anthology of adaptations of works by Philip K Dick.

The series was produced in 2017 and has been on Amazon Streaming across most of the world since 2018 (it's on Stan here in Australia).

> Eleven-year-old Charlie has a close relationship with his father, sharing a love of baseball. One night, while camping out, they see glowing orbs slowly falling from the sky, which the radio news reports are meteoroids. After a day at home, Charlie is uncertain that his father is who, or what, he appears to be, and he is not alone. Charlie and his best friend eventually find a field filled with body doubles grown by the aliens.

Comment: This is the first thing that came to mind when I read the question.  A couple more points that match.  There is a scene in the garage where something happens to the father involving bright light.  It's unclear at the time what was happening but it becomes clear later the father was replaced/absorbed.  The child does use consumer tech with great facility, he researches similar stories on the internet and discovers there is something going on and eventually organises a resistance via hashtags and viral videos.

Comment: @EricNolan I haven't actually seen the episode - though I have seen many from that series, and I've read most of Dick's works so it's what came to my immediate mind when reading the question

Comment: @Horurkol In that case it was a very good guess in my opinion.  The TV episode matches the question very closely even though it is quite different to the short story in the details.